# CSS not selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select all inputs except the inputs inside some div.class. I do not know why it does not work correctly. My structure looks something like below. And why selector :not not work. And what can I do to exclude all inputs from the "exclude" div. Because i want only select inputs: i1,i2.

```js
console.log($("div.exclude input").length);
console.log($("div:not(.exclude) input").length);
console.log($("div input").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div id="tab1">
  <div>
   <div>
    <input id="i1"/>
   </div>
   <input id="i2" />
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="tab2" class="exclude">
  <div>
   <div>
    <input  id="i3" />
   </div>
    <input  id="i4" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All inputs are inside a div which hasn't the class `exclude`

Comment: There are inner divs too .. which get selected

Comment: But In page I have multiple divs and inputs, but I want to select all inputs without inputs inside .exclude. I would like to this line console.log($("div:not(.exclude) input").length);  return:  2 (i1, i2)

Comment: How is this a CSS question? Seems like jQuery

Comment: @j08691 it's a CSS selector question :p

Comment: @JaromandaX How so?

Comment: @j08691 - jQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors (with some additions, sure)

Comment: @JaromandaX But the context of this question is just jQuery. The `css` tag should be for questions that actually involve styling. There's `jquery-selectors` and `css-selectors` for questions about selectors.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Just because jQuery's syntax is CSS-like doesn't mean this question is CSS related.

Comment: Yes I agree with you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input').not('.exclude *')
```

or

```
$('input:not(.exclude *)')
```

These will grab all inputs which are not descendants of elements with the exclude class. You can get more specific on which inputs (maybe only the ones under a certain div or class) but this should get you the exclusion you're looking for.

You can see a working example [here](http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/mOYedY)

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML structure:

```
<div id="tab2" class="exclude">
  <div>
   <div>
    <input  id="i3" />
   </div>
    <input  id="i4" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

each `<input>` is inside at least one `<div>` that does not have the class "exclude". Therefore your selector *is* working but it's not getting the result you want.

Instead, qualify the inputs selected the simple way:

```
console.log($("div input:not(.exclude *)").length);)
```

That selector will first select all of the `<input>` elements (well the ones inside `<div>` elements), but then exclude all of `<input>` elements that have an element with class "exclude" somewhere above them in the DOM.

If the original qualifier of being inside some `<div>` isn't really important, then all you need is `"input:not(.exclude *)"`.

Answer (score 0):

I marked inside your HTML the div that is not with the `exclude` class, and this is why you got 4 inputs on your `console.log($("div:not(.exclude) input").length);`

You can `filter` out the inputs that have parents with the `exclude` class:

```js
console.log($("div.exclude input").length);
console.log($("div:not(.exclude) input").length);
console.log($("div input").length);

console.log($("input").filter(function() { return $(this).parents('.exclude').length > 0}).length);

$("input").filter(function() { return $(this).parents('.exclude').length > 0}).css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div id="tab1">
  <div>
   <div> 
    <input id="i1"/>
   </div>
   <input id="i2" />
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="tab2" class="exclude">
  <div>
   <div> <!-- This div is not with the class explude -->
    <input  id="i3" />
   </div>
    <input  id="i4" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: there are inner divs which does not have the class and they satisfy the selector too.

**Solution**: Add another class to the divs which you want to be part of your selector and then use this new class too .. Like

`<div id="tab1" class="tabs">`  And

`<div id="tab2" class="tabs exclude">`

And then change script to

`$("div.tabs:not(.exclude) input")`

Answer (score 0):

Take this:

```js
console.log($("div.table.exclude input").length);
console.log($("div.table:not(.exclude) input").length);
console.log($("div input").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  
  <div id="tab1" class="table">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input id="i1"/>
      </div>
      <input id="i2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="table exclude">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input  id="i3" />
      </div>
      <input  id="i4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```